# Read a column from csv and save it as pdf

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

I am trying to read data from csv which has url as below:

Policy.csv

```
A  URLnew
1  https://aaa.com/test1.pdf
2  https://aaa.com/test1.pdf
3  https://aaa.com/test1.pdf`
```

I want to read those urls and save these pdf into desktop. Program is running but i cannot open pdf once they are stored. My code is below
`

```
import csv
import os
import requests
import PyPDF2

csv_file = '/Users/test2/python_vscode/NPL/policies.csv'
column_name = 'URL new'
desktop_path = os.path.expanduser('/Users/test1/python_vscode/NPL/files/')

try:
    with open(csv_file, 'r') as file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(file)
        if column_name not in csv_reader.fieldnames:
            print(f"Column '{column_name}' not found in the CSV file.")
        else:
            for row in csv_reader:
                pdf_url = row[column_name]
                pdf_filename = os.path.basename(pdf_url)

                try:
                    # Download the PDF from the URL
                    response = requests.get(pdf_url)
                    if response.status_code == 200:
                        pdf_path = os.path.join(desktop_path, pdf_filename)
                        with open(pdf_path, 'wb') as pdf_file:
                            pdf_file.write(response.content)
                        
                        # Open and read the downloaded PDF
                        with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as pdf_file:
                            pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
                            num_pages = pdf_reader.numPages
                            print(f"Downloaded '{pdf_filename}' to your desktop. This PDF has {num_pages} pages.")
                    else:
                        print(f"Failed to download '{pdf_filename}' from '{pdf_url}'. Status code: {response.status_code}")
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"An error occurred while downloading '{pdf_url}': {str(e)}")

except FileNotFoundError:
    print(f"File '{csv_file}' not found.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
```

I am trying to save it as proper pdf so that I can open them